# need to delete the element from array productid[ ] which is an element of mongodb collection user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**need to delete the element from array productid[ ] which is an element of mongodb collection user tried $pull but doesnt seem to be working seeking help**

```
 router.post('/empty-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("user"+req.body.user +",product" +req.body.productId);
    slug=req.body.productId;
    User.update( {_id: req.body.user}, { $pull: { productId:'slug'}//this productid is array and i need to loop here
    }, function(err, model){})
      console.log(slug);
    meanlogger.log('trash', 'Emptied cart', req.user);

    res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have type conflict problem. what is type of `_id` in `user` collection and `req.body.user`? If `_id` is `ObjectId` and `req.body.user` is string, then user document will not be found for update. Also check `productId` type and `slug` type and remove single quote of `slug` in `$pull: { productId:'slug'}`

Comment: hey thanks for the reply ids are both from same schema so don't think it should be conflict with type.but yeah slug usage i was in fault  but couldn't resolve the issue even after the modification

Comment: I suggest do `findOne` with query `{_id: req.body.user}` to make sure finding work fine  then focus on update query with `$pull`